# If $a$ and $b$ are integers s.t. $2x^2 -ax + 2 > 0$ and $x^2 -b x + 8 \geq 0$ for all real numbers $x$, then the largest possible value of $2a−6b$ is

Tags: inequality, polynomials, quadratics

> If a and b are integers such that $2x^2-ax+2>0$ and $x^2-bx+8≥0$ for all real numbers $x$, then the largest possible value of $2a−6b$ is

Answer: 36.

My attempt: Multiply the first inequality by 2 and second by 6. This gave $4x^2-2ax+2>0$ and $6x^2-6bx+48≥0$. Subtracting the second inequality from the first one, we get $-2ax+6bx≥2x^2+44$. This means $2a-6b≤(2x^2+44)/-x.$ Now how to move further. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: You can't subtract inequalities at all...

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain as to why can't we subtract inequalities?

Comment: $2>1 \land 8>7 \not \implies -6 = 2-8 > 1-7 = -6$.

Comment: Ok. Got the idea. Thanks.

Comment: Actually you *can* subtract inequalities but you must subtract the *opposite* side.  If $a < b$ and $c < d$ then $a - d < b - c$.  You can do that because taking away a *LARGER* thing gives a smaller result.

Comment: In this case you'd get the probably useless $2x^2 - ax + 2 -0 > 0 - (x^2 -bx +8)$ or $2x^2 -ax + 2 > -x^2 +bx -8$.  .... which you already knew as $2x^2 -ax + 2 >0\ge  -x^2 +bx -8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminant for first must be $<0$ and for second $\leq 0$ so $$a^2-16<0\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;b^2-32\leq 0$$

So $$ a\leq 3\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;b\geq -5 \implies 2a-6b\leq 36$$

Comment: How do you determine that the discriminant has to be <0 and  ≤0 for the first and second respectively?

Comment: Because of >  in first and $\geq$ second inequality

Comment: That is in first case your parabole can not go below x-axsis, so it has no zeroes, that is if disciriminat is <.

Comment: In second case parabola can touch x-axsis so it can have at most one root

Comment: I understood this from this. https://www.quora.com/In-a-quadratic-inequality-why-is-the-discriminant-always-less-than-0#

Answer (score 2):

Since these quadratic functions have a positive leading coefficient, they have a *minimum* on $\bf R$, and we know the extremum of a quadratic function $p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ is attained at $x=-\dfrac B{2A}$, so the function  is positive (resp. non-negative) for all $x$ if and only if $A>0$ and $p\Bigl(-\dfrac B{2A}\Bigr)>0\:$ (resp. $\ge 0$).

Here the hypotheses yield 
\begin{cases}2\Bigl(\dfrac a4\Bigr)^2-\dfrac{a^2}4+2>\iff2-\dfrac{a^2}8>0\iff a^2<16, \\[1ex]
\Bigl(\dfrac b2\Bigr)^2-\dfrac{b^2}2+8\ge 0\iff 8-\dfrac{b^2}4\ge 0\iff b^2\le 32,
\end{cases}
Therefore we have $-4<a<4\;$ and $\;-4\sqrt 2 \le b\le 4\sqrt 2$, so that
$$\left.\begin{matrix}-8<2a<8\\-24\sqrt 2\le -6b\le24\sqrt2\end{matrix}\right\}\Rightarrow -8(1+3\sqrt2)<2a-6b<8(1+3\sqrt 2).$$

*Added*:

This solution is for *real* $a$ and $b$.  If ˆ$a$ and $b$ are constrained to be integers, we have the same basic inequalities with $a^2$ and $b^2$, but now we have the equivalence
$$\begin{cases}
a^2<16\\b^2\le 32\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
|a|<4\\ |b|\le 5\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
-3\le a \le 3\\ -5\le b\le 5\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
-6\le 2a \le 6\\ -30\le -6b\le 30\end{cases}$$
so $\;2a-6b\le 36$.

Comment: That would be a good approach if $a,b$ being integers wasn’t a condition. However in this case... stepping down to 36 from 41.94... won’t be justified.

Comment: @Macavity: I've added the very simple  conclusion for integers.

Comment: Yes, of course that conclusion works.. +1

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot subtract inequalities since $a>0$ & $b>0$ does not imply $a-b>0$ (eg. $7>0$ & $8>0$ but $7-8<0$). You should go forward with such problems involving quadratic equations using discriminants as used in the solution above by @greedoid.